# QString formatting will not work qDebug

Tags: c++, qt, qdebug

I try to avoid mixed `QString` and `char*` types in a QT program. I have a  conversation function that returns a pointer of the data inside the `QString`, but I get very strange results. Whats wrong with this code?

Compiler and environment gcc (Debian 4.9.2-10) 4.9.2
Flags via qmake: `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11`

Code snippet:

```c
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <iostream>
#define  PCH(m) ( m.toAscii().data() )

// get the pointer short scripted
const char* CH(QString msg) {
   const char* res = msg.toAscii().data();
   return res;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);

    const QString qformat = "%s does not work!";
    const QString qvalue  = "embedding";

    // Works not
    qDebug(CH(qformat), CH(qvalue));   

    // Works
    qDebug(qformat.toAscii().data(), qvalue.toAscii().data());

    // Works too but macro
    qDebug(PCH(qformat), PCH(qvalue));   

    return app.exec();
}
```

Results

```
%s does not work! does not work!

embedding does not work!

embedding does not work!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you are copying `QString` to function, and return pointer to already destroyed data inside function. This is known undefined behavior, since you are returning pointer to garbage. Return QString.

```
const char* CH(QString msg) {
    const char* res = msg.toAscii().data();
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Thanks thats clear. Is there an other solution  than a macro? .. #define  CH(m) ( m.toAscii().data() ). ?

Comment: why not `qDebug() << m` ?

Comment: I like to use the printf functionality of the logging functions via predefined error codes. Something like this: const QString ERR_UNKOWN_WORK_DIR  = "%s: Unkown work directory %s ";

Comment: @huckfinn Use the formatting built into `QString`, then: `arg` and friends. It's exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: If you want to use qDebug() + format string, use qPrintable(): `qDebug("foo %s", qPrintable(someQString));`

Answer (score 2):

You should be using `qDebug()` and the formatting mechanism built into `QString` itself. You should also use `QStringLiteral` instead of depending on default string conversions - after all you've stated that you care about such things:

```
#include <QtCore>
int main()
{
    const auto qformat = QStringLiteral("%1 does work!");
    const auto qvalue = QStringLiteral("embedding");
    qDebug() << qformat.arg(qvalue);
    qDebug() << qformat.arg(0x7A01173C2, 0, 16);
}
```

The `QStringLiteral`, used on modern compilers, does **not** create an 8-bit C-string. It assembles [a binary internal representation of a `QString`](https://woboq.com/blog/qstringliteral.html) at compile time, and stores it in a read-only memory section of your executable. This is the only way to avoid runtime costs of string encoding.

There is no benefit whatsoever in doing a roundtrip via `QString` if you already have UTF8 encoded string literals or C-style strings that are UTF8 encoded. If you need to use C-style strings/string literals, use them directly with `qDebug`:

```
#include <QtCore>
int main() {
    const char format[] = "%s does not work!";
    const char value[] = "embedding";
    qDebug(format, value);
}
```

If you need to pass temporary C-style strings, use `QByteArray`, but that's really a lot of code with very little to show for it - it's so verbose as to have a very bad code smell. So don't do it like this:

```
#include <QtCore>
QByteArray CH(const QString &msg) {
   return msg.toLocal8Bit();
}

int main()
{
    auto qformat = QStringLiteral("%s does work!");
    auto qvalue = QStringLiteral("embedding");
    qDebug(CH(qformat).constData(), CH(qvalue).constData());
}
```